# How do you get the directory parameter of pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios

In my Resources group in XCode I have a subgroup called "AUDIO", and a subgroup of that called "words_audio".  I have a bunch of sound files I'm trying to get the paths of.  I tried

```
NSArray *pathsForWordAudio = [NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"words_audio"];
```

as well as a few other string parameters, but none of them work.  The hierarchy setup of the folders in the directory is the same as the setup of the group in XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you create a group in XCode - no corresponding folder is created. Moreover, result app bundle for iOS contains no folders at all (except system-dependent like "_CodeSignature" and localizations - "*.lproj"). So pass nil as directory parameter.

Comment: well the problem is there's other groups of mp3's in the AUDIO group that I don't want it to search.

Comment: No idea about solving of this problem except to get all audio files and then manually filter results - for example, by name prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Code lifted from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238143/iphone-ios-copying-files-from-main-bundle-to-documents-folder-causes-crash).