# How can I overwrite the contents of a plist file? (iPhone / iPad)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

I have a plist file in my main app bundle that I want to update via my app. Here is the code I'm using, the problem is that the plist doesn't seem to be getting updated. Is my code incorrect or is there another issue?

```
// Data
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[data setObject:self.someValue forKey:@"Root"];

// Save the logs
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"plist"];
[data writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
```

Please can someone help me out?

Comment: You can't update anything in your app bundle, you'd need to copy it to your Documents directory first.

Comment: I was not aware of this. Please could you advise on how to implement your suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IOS restricts writing to bundled files. If you want a writable plist, you need to copy it to your app's Documents folder and write to it there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, please could you advise on how to do this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238143/iphone-ios-copying-files-from-main-bundle-to-documents-folder-causes-crash, it should help.

Comment: Thank you @JoachimIsaksson! I was stuck on this one. It appears as if iOS lets you overwrite a file bundled with the application but on the app restart all changes are gone. I was pretty stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'm doing it in one of my apps

```
//get file paths
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"document.plist"];
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];  
NSString *bundlePlistPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bundle.plist"];

//if file exists in the documents directory, get it
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentPlistPath]){            
    NSMutableDictionary *documentDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];
        return documentDict;
} 
//if file does not exist, create it from existing plist
else {
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePlistPath toPath:documentPlistPath error:&error];
    if (success) {
        NSMutableDictionary *documentDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];
        return documentDict;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Hope this helps